# Gettting errors after install drupal-8.2.6.nl.po

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I add Language Dutch and import drupal-8.2.6.nl.po

This error is showed on every page: sourcetext 'The file could not be created'

[image]

What should I do?
1. Uninstall dutch language?
2. reinstall dutch language?
3. change language settings?

Comment: This error indicates a file system issue; a file could not be written. So you should check your error logs for the location of the file and make sure your webserver is allowed to write in the specified folder.

Comment: Sounds like your public file system is not writable, which is necessary to generate translation files for JS

Comment: @Berdir Hi thanks the tmp wasn't writable, problem is solved now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(copying from my comment)

Sounds like your public file system is not writable, which is necessary to generate translation files for JS. When you get an error like this, always check the status report page.